# Не получается установить на сервер. Ошибка вида Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii

А самое интересно ставлю на Denver на своём компьютере все работает. Подскажите что с этим можно сделать. 
подробнее можно увидеть здесь

Comment: У вас в ошибке явно указан файл и строка, на которой вызывается ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что сервер на Unix - там регистрочувствительность файлов.
Отлаживайте:

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->controller), 
var_dump(Yii::app()->controller->module) 
и т.д.
```

Смотрите что пустое и не так вызывается.